# FPDF and TV/Film Screenplay formatting

Tags: php, xml, fpdf

I would like to create a PHP script which formats XML into a TV/Film Screenplay, this has proved somewhat more difficult than anticipated. I have created some of the code, however, there are particular places where I get stuck.

**A little background**

In a screenplay there exist multiple tags like character, dialog, sceneheading, transition etc. They have different widths and left and right margins determining the position on the page.

There are two main areas which have come into concern, i.e. I can't figure out:

- Parent/Children XML tags, which cannot be separated.
- If a child tag is long and has to continue to another page, then a subsequent tag must be created in order to show that it is still the parent. For instance, if a Character tag is shown and the dialog to that tag, the child, is calculated (through width, character length and line height) to continue to the next page, then the parent, "character" must be shown again at the top of the subsequent page.

  - Such parent/orphan tags include:
  - "sceneheadng" -> Any tag.
  - "character" -> dialog or parenthetical
  - "parenthetical" -> dialog

Ideally, however, the parent/children tags should be storred in such away that more can be added without lots and lots of code.

Here is what I have so far, after much FPDF configuration and attempts:

```
// Parse the XML string which has been requested from the database.
$xml                        = new SimpleXmlIterator($file, null);
$namespaces                 = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
/*
 * An external function which converts the XML into an ORDERED array.
 * This returns all the attributes of the xml and the following:
 *  "@type"     Refers to the type, i.e. character/dialog etc,
 *  "@content"  What was actually within the tags of the XML.
 */
$source                     = $parseXML($xml, $namespaces);
$saved                      = array ();
// For every line of the XML.
foreach ($source as $index => $line) {
    /*
     * We are going to save the current line of the XML so that we
     * can check the size of the saved cells against the size of the 
     * page. If there is not enough space for specific tags which are
     * required such as character and dialog, then we create a new page.
     * 
     */
    $saved[]                = $line;
    $forward                = false;
    /*
     * Here is where I get somewhat confused - I have attempted to create
     * a mechanism that determines the "@types" which are needed as parents
     * and children of one another. 
     *
     * The $forward variable refers to the possibilty of writing the tag to
     * the PDF. If the parent/orphan is possible or there are non, then it
     * should be able to write.
     */
    if ($forward) {
        $width              = 0;
        foreach ($saved as $index => $value) {
            /*
             * Everything is measured in inches, therefore, I have created a 
             * point() function which turns inches into mm so that FPDF understands
             * everything.
             * 
             * The $format variable is an array which has margins, either top,
             * left or right. We use this to position the Cell of a specific @type
             * so that it appears in the correct format for a TV/Film script.
             *
             * The width variable is deduced via finding the full width of the page,
             * then subtracting the subsequent left and right margin of the said
             * @type.
             */     
            $width          = (point ($setting["width"])
                            - (point ($format[$value["@type"]]["margin-left"])
                            +  point ($format[$value["@type"]]["margin-right"])));
            /*
             * The $pdf variable is that of the FPDF Class.
             */
            $pdf->SetLeftMargin (point($format[$value["@type"]]["margin-left"]));
            $pdf->SetRightMargin (point($format[$value["@type"]]["margin-right"]));
            // Formatting purposes.
            $pdf->Ln (0);   
            $pdf->MultiCell (
                $width,
                point ($setting["line-height"]), //Line height? Still needs fixing.
                $value["@content"], // Physical text
                1); // A temporary border to see what's going on.
        }
        // Reset the $saved, after no more parent/children?
        $saved              = array ();
    }
}
```

Additionally, I have written a function which calculates the height of the combined "$saved" lines:

```
function calculate_page_breaks ($saved_lines, $act_upon = true) {
    $num_lines          = 0;
    foreach ($saved_lines as $value) {
        $column_width   = (point ($setting["width"])
                        - (point ($format[$type][$value["@type"]]["margin-left"])
                        +  point ($format[$type][$value["@type"]]["margin-right"])));
        $num_lines      += ceil($pdf->GetStringWidth($value["@content"]) / ($column_width - 1));
    }
    $cell_height        = 5 + 1; // have cells at a height of five so set to six for a padding
    $height_of_cell     = ceil($num_lines * $cell_height); 
    $space_left         = point($setting["height"]) - $pdf->GetY();
    $space_left         -= point($format[$type]["margin-bottom"]);
    // test if height of cell is greater than space left
    if ($height_of_cell >= $space_left) {
        // If this is not just a check, then we can physically "break" the page.
        if ($act_upon) {
            $pdf->Ln ();                        
            $pdf->AddPage (); // page break
            $pdf->SetTopMargin ($point($format[$type]["margin-top"]));
            $pdf->SetLeftMargin ($point($format[$type]["margin-left"]));
            $pdf->SetRightMargin ($point($format[$type]["margin-right"]));
            $pdf->MultiCell (100,5,'','B',2); // this creates a blank row for formatting reasons
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

*Edit*

I have discovered that LaTeX offers a Screenplay Class (http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/screenplay/screenplay.pdf), however, I have searched far and wide to find a PHP-based tool to convert LaTeX to PDF, but have had no success. I understand that LaTeX runs on the server side, however I still require a PHP-based command process in order to generate said PDF files using LaTeX.

Additionally, installing binaries, libraries or tools on to the server is a no-no. The tool at my disposal is PHP and the functionalities it has built in. Any class or PHP tool that can convert LaTex to PDF is incredibly useful.

Comment: @Blender: No, but how does this help with margins/cell formatting/page breaks etc?

Comment: Because that is what Latex is made for ;) It's used to typeset magazines, books, textbooks, research papers, etc. It generates PDF files.

Comment: There's even a whole `Screenplay` class you can utilize: http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/screenplay/screenplay.pdf

Comment: @Blender How does one start writing a PHP Parser for Latex, then to PDF?

Comment: Latex is parsed by Tex, not PHP. You need to make a `text -> latex` script in PHP and then run `latex` in the background to generate the PDF.

Comment: @Blender I gathered, however, this does not address my initial question. I do not wish to run third party material (i.e. server side execution) in order to parse anything, instead, a compiler of Latex, for example, would be far more sufficient. For you see, I would create a parser in PHP from XML to Latex, and then use (if it exists) a PHP Latex to PDF parser. Does such plugin exist?

Comment: Latex is it's own thing. Whatever you might call a plugin will require Latex to be installed and will call it one way or another. Latex is compiled (think of it like C++), not really parsed.

Comment: You can use ghostscript to convert to PDF in latex.  I believe this is how [TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org/) works.  But to get to latex from PHP [here](http://sixthform.info/steve/wordpress/?p=13) is one solution -- you have to install some stuff on the server -- for WordPress sites . . . not sure if it is still valid code, but it's a start.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://jelix.org/articles/en/manual-1.1/responselatex2pdf

Also i would use TCPDF instead of FPDF. I have been using FPDF for ages and recently tried TCPDF, the last one has many more options and is mutch more flexible. Perhaps you can even get it working without latex.

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirements, I would recommend using **online web services** to push your LateX file and get a compiled PDF in return.

This means you get a full PDF file without any compilation, no installing, **just pure PHP-based** web services and API.

There are a number of online solutions, some are free, so please check the one that fits your need : [Compiling documents online](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online)

Good luck !